# Best Device For Learning About Sending TCP Packets

Tags: television, smart-device, ip-camera

I'm not sure if this is the right site to be posting this question, however out of them all from what I could see, this was the one that stuck out most.
I'm a self learner, and am currently learning (well trying too) about TCP packets with payloads.
I did some research and from what I have learnt, security cameras, smart tv's and well any hardware really that can be connected to, can have packets sent to them that can perform certain tasks, eg a certain packet with the correct header and payload can turn a tv off, change the channel and so on.
My question is, is there a certain device eg camera, tv and so on, that I can buy that can help me learn more about this topic, if someone could lead the way and point me in the direction of a device that has such a thing and even with documentation of the tcp diagram, that would help me out a lot, I'm using C#
If this is the wrong site to be posting this question, please let me know so I can go to the correct StackExchange site, Thank you

Comment: I know that the main purpose of the hardware is for you to learn about TCP packets, but are there any other details that you can give us? For example, a price that you want to stay under. You can easily spend a grand or two on a smart tv, but I would expect a much cheaper price for an internet camera.

Comment: You can learn about TCP packets with any ordinary computer or phone, you don't need a special device nor will one help you.

Comment: Seconding @RubyJunk. Unless you have something specific you want to be looking at, you probably don't need specific hardware to look at networking.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with software - [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org) works on both Windows and Linux and lets you see all the packets reaching your computer. It's free.

Also read about [magic packets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) - wake on LAN has nothing to do with TCP. In fact it does not even use IP!

Going further - some better routers, such as the [MikroTik Hex](https://mikrotik.com/product/RB750Gr3) allow you to sniff all the traffic going through them.

As for a TV or an IP camera which has open documentation for it's custom TCP protocols - I wouldn't count on the availability of such a device.